# Keep sound from video playing in background

Tags: android, video, media-player

I have some serious trouble with VLC player on my Android device, so I have started using KMPlayer.

The only thing I miss from VLC is the ability to continue listening to the sound from videos even while switching to other apps or locking the screen.

Is there any good video player that does this, other than VLC?

Samsung I9305, rooted stock Android 4.4.4, Xposed Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/137311/96277) that [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) has this feature, as well as many other great features. The video background playback setting is not enabled by default, so it has to be enabled by the user. More info can be found in the linked answer.

Downside is that the free version is ad-supported. Also, it needs a plugin for DTS/AC3 audio.

The background play notification:

[image: MX Player Background Play Notification]

The background audio playback setting:

[image: Background Playback setting]